# How can I set a flag in javascript for a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, global-variables, flags, local-variables

I have this Twitter scanner (a Google Chrome extension), that I want to execute this IF statement exactly once. After that I still want it to be able to scan for other `shoeName`, but my flag that I set keeps getting reset.

Here is my code:

```
function twitterScan() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
        tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;
    }
    var flag = true;
    var flag1 = true;

    //if (document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;

    if (tweet[0].match(shoeName) == shoeName && flag == true||(tweet[0].match(shoeName1) == shoeName1 && flag1 == true) {
        if(tweet[0].match(shoeName) == shoeName) 
            flag = false;
        if(tweet[0].match(shoeName1) == shoeName1)
            flag1 = false;
        document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
        tFunction = "get outa here";
        shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From where is twitterScan() called?

Have you tried moving flag & flag1 outside the function?

```
var flag = true;
var flag1 = true;
function twitterScan() { ... }
```

Comment: it is getting called right outside the function twitterscan    setTimeout(tFunction, 10); declaring the variables outside the fucntion doesnt work.. I am trying to keep the twitter so its listening the entire time for the next link that I  am intrested in

Comment: Exactly! That is why you need to pull these variables outside the function as running the function every 10 milliseconds updates their values.